# concealing 8160 DC, 8160 AC, 8160 MV errors in frame error in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, yuv

I have an mp4 video and I want to convert it to yuv. This video has some errors inside. I need to convert it to yuv because the target is getting PSNR between the distorted yuv and the original yuv.

I am using FFmpeg for this purpose. I get several of the consecutive following error:

```
[h264 @ 0x1c0ce00] concealing 8160 DC, 8160 AC, 8160 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x1bce920] concealing 8160 DC, 8160 AC, 8160 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x1be2c80] concealing 8160 DC, 8160 AC, 8160 MV errors in P frame
frame=14964 fps= 31 q=-0.0 size=45453150kB time=00:09:58.56 
bitrate=622080.0kbit[h264 @ 0x1b482a0] concealing 8160 DC, 8160 AC, 8160 MV 
errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0x1be9780] concealing 8160 DC, 8160 AC, 8160 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x1b827a0] concealing 8160 DC, 8160 AC, 8160 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x1b89ee0] concealing 8160 DC, 8160 AC, 8160 MV errors in P frame
```

Then, in the converted yuv video,  these frames are the gray scenes while these frames are fine in the mp4 video. So, I am wondering why FFmpeg can't convert them to yuv.
I am using the following command to convert mp4 to yuv:

```
ffmpeg -i d_video.mp4 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25  -s 1920x1080 -y d_yuv.yuv
```

could you please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

After some efforts, I understood that this problem is solved in the upgraded FFmpeg version. The one that I had was 2.8 and I upgraded it to 4.1.1. Now it is perfectly working.